# Hyperlink not working in edge browser but working in chrome browser

Tags: html, browser, microsoft-edge

I have embedded below hyperlink in html page(just linked another application page) and not working when click the link using edge browser but is working from chrome browser.

```
<a href="https://xx.com/site/controller.exec?objectId=12222">This is Link</a>
```

Edge Browser Version : 88.0.7.5.68

"https://xx.com/site/controller.exec?objectId=12222"

Also, I have noticed below issues in **edge browser**:

```
<html><META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="0"><script 
type="text/javascript">location="/site/Login.exec?action=ssoLogin&redirect=true"</script></html>
```

Please advise what cause this issue and why is not working in edge browser.
[image]

console issue:

Comment: Please inform us, which exact version of the Edge browser you are using for making this test? How exactly you have embedded the link in a page? Above mentioned JS code doesn't look proper. What is the purpose of it?

Comment: The purpose of link is to refer another application from My application. This is just linked as html page to open another page or tab.

Comment: Do you mean your link looks like `<a href="https://xx.com/site/controller.exec?objectId=12222">This is Link</a>`? I try to check this link and it is navigating to the mentioned URL. Do you see the `Response should include 'content-type' header.` while clicking on the link or it is there from the loading of the page? If possible please post the snapshot of the error message. What if you try to paste the link URL directly in the Edge browser address bar and press the Enter key? Does it navigate properly?

Comment: yes , same as coded and linked. If copy and paste complete url(https://xx.com/site/controller.exec?objectId=12222) again it is not working but if i try https://xx.com/site/ is working.

Comment: If the URL is a public URL then just for testing purposes can you share it here? We can try to test it on our side to check for the result. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a configuration gap between Chrome and Edge. As both browsers are running Chromium under the hood.

Please make sure you have the same configuration:

- Proxy settings
- DNS
- Other network related configurations.